# How can we print the user id in the teams channel using azure devops pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, microsoft-teams, azure-webhooks

I have a requirement to print user id (CI triggered user id) in the teams channel as soon the files updated in the GCP buckets & the azure CI triggered.

Can someone please suggest me how can I proceed with.

Please find the code below which I have tried:

```
def get_triggered_user_id():
    organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organisation_name}/"
    project_name = os.environ.get('ComponentName')
    build_id = os.environ.get('BUILD_BUILDID')  # Assuming this environment variable is available

    api_url = f"{organization_url}{project_name}/_apis/build/builds/{build_id}?api-version=6.0"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Basic {os.environ["SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"]}'  ##Here the id is not generating in my logs in devops pipeline
    }

    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    triggering_user_id = response.json().get('requestedFor').get('id')
    return triggering_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you need to print the user id to the Microsoft teams channel.

To meet your requirement, you can use the Incoming Webhook in Microsoft Teams.

Here are the steps:

1.Create a webhook in Microsoft Teams -> Channel

(a) Navigate to the channel where you want to add the webhook and select (•••) Connectors.

(b) Search for **Incoming Webhook**, and add it.

(c) Click Configure and provide a name for your webhook.

(d) Copy the Webhook URL

2.We can install **pymsteams** to connect the webhook.

**Install pymsteams**

```
pip install pymsteams
```

3.Use the following python script sample

```
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("<Microsoft Webhook URL>")
myTeamsMessage.text("useridinfo")
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Teams incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet)

On the other hand, you can also consider directly using the [Azure Pipelines Teams Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops) to connect to Azure DevOps in MS teams.

Comment: Hi ,
All these things were done. The code which I provided is a code within cloud function which is triggered by running a pipeline. I want the id of the person who runs the pipeline to print the status of the cloud function in Microsoft teams notification

Comment: @srilakshmiponnaganti Do you mean that print the result of the pipeline status instead of user iD?

Comment: No No, I want the userId who run the pipeline to use it later in the CF main.py

Comment: @srilakshmiponnaganti Can you provide more details about the requirement ? Is CF main.py run in Pipeline? And do you want to pass the obtained userID to CF main.py? From the description of the question, it seems that you only want to pass the obtained userid to teams

Comment: yes this is correct..i want to pass obtained userid from devops pipeline to CF main.py which is in pipeline itself and the status of CF i am trying to pass to teams channel. The userId here should be the person id who is running that pipeline which makes CF trigger.

Comment: If the CF main.py is in the same pipeline, you can directly use the Predefined variable: $(Build.RequestedForId) in Build Pipeline, it will shows the user id who request the pipeline run. You dont need to use script to get it. Refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml